# Controlled event handling flow in qooxdoo

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

## Preface

The problem described below might be topical for virtually any event-driven JS framework and any application that processes incoming data/event stream. For the sake of definiteness, let's imagine a web-based IM (Facebook chat-like) using [qooxdoo](http://qooxdoo.org) framework.

The application receives incoming event stream (via WebSocket, for example) and re-emits events to its internal classes:

[image]

Events are processed, roughly speaking, in two stages. First stage handlers are mostly alerts (play a sound on incoming message, display a [web notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API) etc.) Second stage does actual data processing and display. Both stages handlers are invoked simultaneously as events arrive.

This model provides good code decoupling between the application and the handlers, allowing to add/remove and enable/disable them independently. However...

## The Problem

...as the application evolves, turns out there can be dependencies between the stages. Some stage 1 handlers should block those of stage 2 (ex., an incoming voice recording should not autoplay until sound alert has completed). Some might even show a user confirmation, and cancel the whole remaining chain if the confirmation has not been given. The event handling in qooxdoo assumes that all the handlers are invoked (nearly) simultaneously, and there is no control over the order and timing of handler invocations.

How do we introduce the required control, while remaining within the event model and not sacrificing its benefits (low coupling, etc.)?

## Solution

The candidate solution employs [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). By default, qooxdoo event handlers do not return anything. Why not making them (optionally) return a Promise? In this case, a promise-aware event mediator should be introduced:

[image]

The handlers now should be subscribed to the mediator (this is omitted from the diagram for the sake of clarity). The mediator, in addition to the standard `on`/`off` methods, should implement an `after` method with the following semantics:

- `after(String name, Function listener, var ctx?)` - invoke handler after *all* other handlers for this event
- `after(String name, Integer id, Function listener, var ctx?)` - invoke handler after another handler with a known ID
- `after(String name, (Class|String) id, Function listener, var ctx?)` - invoke handler after all other handlers of some known class (could be derived from `this` argument of the corresponding call)

Thus, we extend the existing event semantics at two points:

- event handlers may now return Promises;
- an `after` method is introduced for an event emitter/mediator.

The emitter/mediator should resolve dependencies and wire handler invocations to the corresponding `then()` blocks of Promises.

The proposed solution seems to satisfy both requirements: 1) it implements dependencies between event handlers, 2) it allows to stay within the event handling paradigm. Are there any pitfalls? Can it be done better/cleaner? Any critique and advice is welcome.

Comment: I think the best way of evaluating such ideas is by implementing them ... do you have any code to share ? On https://gitter.im/qooxdoo/qooxdoo you might find some people to discuss this with.

Comment: Promises are being integrated into Qooxdoo and are in a pull request under review (this cool new feature was largely prompted by your question here, so thank you for your suggestion :) ).  The pull request is https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/pull/9232, if you would like to take a look please do - it would be great to know that it solves your use case.